# Is it safe to disable "Internet Information Services" feature in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, iis

My machine runs IIS 10 - it came without my knowledge during an upgrade from Windows 7 (as mentioned in Windows 10 upgrade come with Internet Information Services 10?) - now I wonder: Is it safe to disable/turn it off temporarily or even uninstall it permanently, or are there any (life supporting or not) services which require it? If there's no straightforward answer to that, how may I find out?

Comment: The Windows 10 Upgrade does not install IIS, unless IIS was already present on your Windows 7 system. If you don't need it anymore, uninstall it.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf Do you have some evidence for that statement? "IIS 10 is included in Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10" from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services and https://blogs.iis.net/davidso/http2 suggest otherwise...

Comment: @DavidPostill - Of course IIS is included in Windows 10 and Server 2016, but it is not installed by default. And the upgrade process from 7 to 10 doesn't just install it. If you want IIS you have to enable/install it.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf, if there was IIS10 on my machine before the upgrade, at least it wasn't launched by default on system startup, yet now on a fresh Win7->Win10 upgrade it does

Comment: @HumanInDisguise - I have no way to test that, but I agree the 7 to 10 upgrade does change some configuration settings.

Comment: You can disable IIS in the programs and features settings in Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're running a web server of some kind, you don't need it.  Nothing inherent to Windows depends on IIS.

You can disable it via Programs and Features -> Turn Windows Features On or Off.

[image: Add/remove IIS Feature]

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Eventually, just when unchecking the checkmark on IIS a popup asked me to confirm if I wanted to deactivate three services which depend on it: named-pipe-activation and two other activation ways whose names I omitted to record. I've confirmed the checkbox, machine still works well. Just FYI for whoever reads this in the future.